# Starter material for BDD?

Tags: bdd

Anyone knows of some good place to start doing BDD ?

I've been doing TDD for ~ 2 years now (my compliments to misters Kent Beck and Martin Fowler). I kinda feel next step is BDD but I want some hands-on experience before pushing my team there. Unlike TDD and XP which have de-facto standard books to start, I couldn't find any such material on BDD. I'm not looking for get-familiar kinda material but the kind that gets you doing it in real world. Thanks in advance.

P.S: Preferably PHP and/or Scala but anything would do [please, no Ruby ;) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RSpec Book - yes, it's Ruby, but there's really not much else out there in print. The first few chapters give a solid grounding of the princples, with barely a mention of Ruby. One of the authors is Dan North, the inventor of the term 'BDD'.